# Android. Как правильно сделать Popup menu

Tags: android, menu, popup, popupmenu

у меня есть кейсы, которые привязаны к иконкам и мне надо как-то реализовать код вместо `Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();

  switch (id) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_filter:
        Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
  }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Вот код, который мне нужно реализовать в case:**

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);           
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    popup.show();
}
});
```

***Как правильно переписать код, чтоб не было button и он смог бы нормально обрабатываться по нажатию на иконку.***

Comment: Не сен вопрос. Вы не можете копирнуть ваш же код?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну у меня есть case, в одном из них прописан id кнопки. (menu_filter) и в нем я хочу написать вызов выпадающего меню.

Comment: Так вы же сами привели код, который вам надо туда вставить. Т.е. у вас нет проблемы...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб он не обрабатывается. Выдает ошибки. и мне кнопка button вообще не нужна. В коде просто слушатель прописан уже, а в моем первом коде уже прописаны слушатели case, при выборе которых обрабатывается код и мне надо совместить эти два когда как-то, чтоб  не было конфликтов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб P.S. мне не нужна кнопка `button` у меня уже есть кнопка `menu_filter`

Comment: Возможно, если вы приведёте сообщение об ошибке, станет немного понятнее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45393/discussion-between-satanist-devilov-and-).

Comment: Не, в чаты я не хожу